# How to sort 'MMM YYYY' date string according to date?

Tags: java, android, date, sorting

I'm trying to sort 'MMM YYYY' string according to date in Java (android).

For example:

```
Input:
---------
Sep 2019
Oct 2018
Nov 2019
Oct 2021
Nov 2011

Output:
---------
Nov 2011
Oct 2018
Sep 2019
Nov 2019
Oct 2021
```

Comment: So you want to sort them by their chronological value? If so, say so. Your example data is not obvious.

Comment: Don’t keep your months as strings in your list. Just as you wouldn’t put numbers into an array of strings. Use proper data types. In this case keep a list of `YearMonth` objects. Sort them in natural order. If and when you need to give string output, format each `YearMonth` object into a string in your `MMM yyyy` format (or which format the receiver prefers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Stream` of the given strings, parse each string of the `Stream` into `YearMonth`, sort the `Stream`, map each `YearMonth` element to the original format and finally, collect the `Stream` into a collection.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<String> sorted = Stream.of(
                "Sep 2019",
                "Oct 2018",
                "Nov 2019",
                "Oct 2021",
                "Nov 2011"
        )
        .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, dtf))
        .sorted()
        .map(ym -> dtf.format(ym))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
        // Display the list
        sorted.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Nov 2011
Oct 2018
Sep 2019
Nov 2019
Oct 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/um2dpf)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not clear. I’ll assume your goal is to sort them by their chronological value.

## `YearMonth` class

1. Parse each value as a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).
2. Collect those `YearMonth` objects into a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html).
3. Iterate that collection, generating your desired outputs.